# Decreasing or emptying the entropy pool?

Tags: random

I work with virtual machines a lot, and they seem to generally be low on entropy (no mouse or other entropy-generating inputs). A bug with my software has surfaced, and I *think* it's due to running out of entropy. I want to test it, but it only happens occasionally, and is hard to reproduce.

How can I empty out the entropy pool to test how my software behaves when it has run out?

(Note: I'm calling someone else's code that uses `dev/random`, so using `dev/urandom` instead to prevent blocking isn't an option.)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should make sure that it's really the depletion of the random pool that produces the bug in your software.  You can run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` to test the available entropy on your system and check if it hits zero.

Secondly, AFAIK (I haven't tested these commands) you can decrease the entropy pool by setting the appropriate variable in /proc.  To set it to 32 bits:

`echo 32 > /proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize`

or

`sysctl -w kernel.random.poolsize=32`

Comment: "Make[ing] sure that it's really the depletion of the random pool" is exactly what I'm trying to do. :P Anyway, your commands both tell me permission denied, even as root.

Comment: If you ran those commands, you'd find that they don't work at all. **The pool size is hardcoded in `/drivers/char/random.c:275` so you have to recompile the kernel to change it.**

Answer (score 3):

`cat /dev/random` will continuously use up entropy as it becomes available, keeping it at or near zero. It's not perfect, but it's simple.